# SQL Server - CASE WHEN in WHERE clause with DATEDIFF function

Tags: sql-server, where-clause, datediff, case-when

I am trying to execute the below where statement with case when and `DATEDIFF` function. but am getting syntax error. please help me.

```
WHERE
    -- primary contract is Flowing
    CTS.ContractStatusIdentifier = 'FLW'                                         
    AND (CASE 
            WHEN VMO.ProvinceOrStateCode = 'ON'
               THEN DATEDIFF (dd, CTR.RenewalDate, @currentdate) >= 75
               ELSE DATEDIFF (dd, CTR.RenewalDate, @currentdate) >= 45)
    AND VMO.ProvinceOrStateCode IN ('ON','AB')
```

Comment: Two problems: first of all, the `CASE` needs to be terminated by an `END` which is missing. And secondly, `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** that returns a single, atomic value - you cannot selectively execute one code block or another, you need to **return** a value (like a number or a string) - not a code block

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the `WHERE` clause syntax

```
AND (CASE 
        WHEN VMO.ProvinceOrStateCode = 'ON'
           THEN DATEDIFF (dd, CTR.RenewalDate, @currentdate) >= 75
           ELSE DATEDIFF (dd, CTR.RenewalDate, @currentdate) >= 45)
```

is invalid. To make it simple is pretty simple, please try

```
AND DATEDIFF (dd, CTR.RenewalDate, @currentdate)
    >= (CASE 
           WHEN VMO.ProvinceOrStateCode = 'ON'
               THEN 75
               ELSE 45
        END)
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

SELECT [supp_call_tckt_num], UPPER([assigned_to]) as assigned_to,

assigned_date, close_date, diffday = CASE WHEN close_date is null then

datediff(d,assigned_date,getdate()) else

datediff(d,assigned_date,close_date) end,

UPPER([call_source]) as call_source,

UPPER([account_type]) as account_type, [mdn],

UPPER([status]) as status, UPPER([company_name]) as company_name,

UPPER([rep_id]) as rep_id, UPPER([caller_first_name]) caller_first_name,

UPPER([caller_last_name]) as caller_last_name, [account_number],

UPPER([network]) as network, UPPER([issue_type]) as issue_type,

UPPER([problem]) as problem, UPPER([subtype]) as subtype, UPPER([prob_desc_res])

as prob_desc_res, UPPER([notes]) as notes, [ticket_number] FROM
[ewts_tracker] with (NOLOCK) WHERE [ewts_tracker].[escalated] =

'Yes' AND
datediff (d,isnull(assigned_date,getdate()),close_date) >= '3'